# Attaching a Running Process to a Terminal in Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to find a way to attach a running process to a new terminal window so I can interact with it and manipulate it using the terminal. Reptyr is a tool for Linux that appears to do exactly what I want to do, but is there any solution for Mac?

For context: I run a Minecraft server and have it auto start with cron. This has the server run in the background, not attached to any terminal.

Is there any way to do what I'm asking on Mac? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead start a screen session with cron and later attach to it:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS minecraft /path/to/java /path/to/minecraft.jar etc..
```

Later, you can `screen -R minecraft` to get to the server console, and `Ctrl+A, D` to detach again.